Trouble when trying to connect MongoDB Atlas with Flask-Pymongo
I used to have a mongodb server on my computer and everything worked just fine. When I tried to deploy the server to MongoDB atlas it broke.
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "..."
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "..."

mongo = PyMongo(app)

# Rest of the code

The problem is that mongo.db is None and when I'm trying to do mongo.db.users I get an error that NoneType doesn't have users attribute, but given that it used to work in the past I believe that MongoDB atlas didn't connect properly with Flask-Pymongo and that the script is correct. I setted up the Mongo cluster, created a user and password and added my ip to network access (I even tried adding 0.0.0.0/0, which allows access from everyone). I'm so confused. Can someone help me?

I solved it but by using a different module. I just used the regular PyMongo module instead of the expanded Flask-Pymongo. The only difference in the code is that instead of app.config["MONGO_URI"]=..., you define the mongo uri like this: client = MongoClient(...). This was probably because the module was broken or something, but if you suspect I did something wrong in the first place, please let me know.
